# Migrate database with groovy script in grails

Tags: groovy, migration

I have currently a database need to be migrated in grails. I have used

```
def sql =groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(url,username,password,driver)
```

and after that I call

```
sql.eachRow("""select *\
                     from kontakt k join kommunikation c on k.kontakt_id = c.kontakt_id \
                     join kommunikationsmittel cm on c.kommittel_id = cm.kommittel_id \
                     join kommunikationstyp ct on c.komtyp_id = ct.komtyp_id \
                     join adresse a on a.Kontakt_ID = k.Kontakt_ID
                      """) {row->
     }
```

The thing is that I can access the columnname via row.Strasse, row.PLZ and so on, but if there are two columns, which have the same name inside two different tables. How can I access different columns?
For example in 'Kommunikationsmittel' table there is a column 'Bezeichnung'. In 'Kommunikationstyp' there is also a column 'Bezeichnung'. How can I access via row?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, if you have duplicate field names, it's going to cause problems.

Your options are to either change the select so it is specific, and you can rename the conflicting fields, ie:

```
SELECT k.Strasse as kstrasse, a.Strasse AS astrasse FROM.....
```

Or, you can use the `metaData` for the row to get at all of the fields, as in this example:

```
sql.eachRow( '''...''' ) { row ->
  row.getMetaData()*.columnName.eachWithIndex { name, index ->
    println "$name = ${row[ index ]}"
  }
}
```

By the way, you don't need `\` chars in your SQL as you are using `"""`, so lines will continue till the trailing `"""`

Comment: the second method you mentioned, how can I write it? ColumnName is for example the duplicated Columnname? and what is the name and what is the index

Comment: You should be able to run that code as it stands to print out names and values.  `row.getMetaData()*.columnName` returns a `List` containing all the names of the columns in this row.  `eachWithIndex` will iterate through this list of names, and call the closure passing `name` and `index`